# How to trigger Jenkins downstream job from script but not manually through Jenskins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jira, jenkins-pipeline

From Jenkins plugin (ie. Delivery Pipeline, Parameterized Trigger), we could setup a pipeline which contains multiple jobs in sequence, for instance: Build -> Unit Test -> Deploy To DEV.

Now, for each pipeline, we want to stop after "Unit Test" because we need to wait for someone to approve the deployment before it can go on (We use JIRA as the tracking system for this). 
Say when, someone approves the deployment ticket in JIRA, we already setup a post action to fire and trigger a job in Jenkins, say "Deploy To Dev" in this case. However, this job will run independently outside the pipeline.
Is there a way, we can trigger the down stream job from script within an instance of a pipeline so it can carry over all the parameters from upstream and shown as part of the pipeline?

Thx

Comment: You either have to modify your post action to write a file on a shared path where your Jenkins pipeline can wait and monitor it after the Unit Test Stage or use rest api to query the Jira request status and then proceed with the next step based on the outcome